# Updating Access Table From C# code

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to update a field based on a condition 
if age <25 then class = 10 else class = 20;

so far I have tried these

```
 cmd = new OleDbCommand("update workClass Set Class = 10  when " + ds.Tables["no"].Rows[i][1] + " < 25   else Set Class =  20 ", con);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

second

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("update workClass Set Class = 10  where" + ds.Tables["no"].Rows[i][1] + " < 25   else Set Class =  20 ", con);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get this error message 
 
note the ds.tables return 33in the first iteration so that bit works fine

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '10  when 33 < 25 
>   else  Class =  20'.

Comment: What does `ds.Tables["no"].Rows[i][1]` return ?

Comment: it returns an int 33 @Igor

Comment: Sorry, this does not make sense. Why are you essentially hard coding 33 and comparing it to 25? Is this actually coming from each record and are you doing this is some sort of loop?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to do this across the board for all records and for each record compare the records value in column X to 25? It would help if you included the code around these 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WHEN clause in the JET engine that powers the Microsoft Access Database.
You need to use the [IIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ECF-C629-48A3-9900-647539C764E3) like this

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"update workClass Set Class = IIF(" + 
    ds.Tables["no"].Rows[i][1] + " < 25, 10, 20)", con);
```

However I suggest you to use a parameterized query to avoid possible parsing error and sql Injection

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"update workClass Set Class = IF(@value < 25, 10, 20)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 
    Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["no"].Rows[i][1]);
```

Comment: I have a feeling the OP is using this in a loop and reading the value in a data table and then applying it to an update. I think there is much more wrong with the code but that code is not included in the question....

Comment: @Igor perhaps you are correct but, as it stands, his problem (the syntax error) is caused by an unknown (to access) keyword WHEN. Probably we could optimize the code if we know more.

Comment: yes I did an awful mistake by using a loop I was working with insert earlier and that confused me.. never the less the problem wasn't that..
@Igor

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this is what you are after.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE workClass SET [Class] = IIF([Age] < 25, 10, 20)", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

What is missing though is a descriminator so you only update a specific record or set of records based on a filter. As written the query you have and this one updates all records each time it is executed. To add the `where` clause be sure to add the filter using a parameter and do not use string concatenation.

Example:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE workClass SET [Class] = IIF([Age] < 25, 10, 20) WHERE [someId] = ?", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@someId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = yourIdValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

*It is important to note that parameters are ordered in Ms Access and not named. The first parameter encountered in the query must correspond to the first parameter in the parameter collection.*